# I want to cleanup junk in a win7 installation, what're the hot spots?

Tags: windows-7

I only have a c: of 14 gigs or something, and I'm constantly running out of space in c:.

Are there any big pieces of junk I could safely delete to save space? So far I've only turned system protection and hibernation off, and it looks good.

I barely use any windows built-in stuff, besides mspaint and calc, I'm willing to get rid of anything, or so I think...

Comment: do you use disk clean up?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, upgrade the hard drive when you can, W7 continually grows in size, especially when you do Windows Updates, and install programs over time.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA thanks, that's the first thing off mind, and actually I do it on a regular basis.

Comment: @Moab I do have a hard drive of 1T, however I have Ubuntu installed on it and don't want a dual boot. The current drive is 160G, I could have found some space but just don't want to do the dirty partitioning until last minute.

Comment: BTW, I know where windows update caches downloads, and I clean that regularly too.

Answer (score 0):

Give [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) a shot; it's very useful for clearing up unwanted/un-needed space.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use 3rd party app like [quick clean](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/clean-junk-files-in-windows-7-vista-with-quick-clean) or [MSConfig CleanUp Utility](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-junk-windows-startup-entries-with-msconfig-cleanup-utility/)

Answer (score 0):

Try turning Windows features off. Type in "windows features" at the start search and hit enter. Most of the stuff in there is safe to disable, though some you may not want to (Internet Explorer, .NET Framework...)

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't remove the programs... it merely remove them from the user interface...